# automation of plugin installations

Tags: plugins, installation, automation

My business is building and establishing websites for all kinds of businesses and companies.
So, every time I start a new site for a client of mine, I have to install the same plugins over and over again.
Is there a way to automate this? I mean, set up a "manifest" of needed plugins and run it on a site, then it will automatically install (and activate) all the plugins in the list.
There used to be a plugin called "Install Profiles", but it is very (!) old and not updated (latest WP version supported is 3.x)...

Answer (score 0):

Check out  [TGM-Plugin-Activation](https://github.com/thomasgriffin/TGM-Plugin-Activation) plugin.

> TGM Plugin Activation is a PHP library that allows you to easily
>   require or recommend plugins for your WordPress themes (and plugins).
>   It allows your users to install and even automatically activate
>   plugins in singular or bulk fashion using native WordPress classes,
>   functions and interfaces. You can reference pre-packaged plugins,
>   plugins from the WordPress Plugin Repository or even plugins hosted
>   elsewhere on the internet.